# What formula to make an element fit inside a div

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to figure out how to make an element fit (like object-fit) into another div.

That specific element is an Image Container (div.ratio-box), which has a intrinsic aspect ratio css (the padding bottom hack to avoid page jump).

The problem is that with portrait image, the Image Container (div.ratio-box) is overflowing the parent (div.slide-cell) . So what I want to do is to calculate a new width base for (div.slide-cell.portrait) on the following known value:

- Img Height,
- Img Width,
- Parent's width
- Parent's margin from the browser window

https://jsfiddle.net/5d6zrueh/3/

```
<div id="slider">
 <div class="flickity-viewport">
  <div class="flickity-slider">
   <div class="slide-cell portrait is-selected">
    <div class="ratio-box centered" style="padding-bottom:150.06002401%;">
     <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/166x250">
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Hope it makes sense to you.

Comment: display: inline-flex doesn't do what you want?

Comment: You meant on the div.portrait? Not sure how that would work with this case.

Comment: The image container .ratio-box. The display: inline-flex makes the parent aware of children width/height. I'm not sure if this is what you want so just try on your code i can't access jsfiddle.

Comment: Just tried to applied that but still, doesn't help much. The point is to find a mathematical solution base on the padding-bottom value (that off course can change), and the parent container width.